# Как сделать чтоб низ CardView был волнистым как у чека?

Tags: java, android

Есть сервис откуда приходит ответ (чек на покупку). Показываю его в `CardView`, но хочется сделать эту карту похожей на чек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так же волнисто обрезать `Card View`?

Comment: вы можете использовать собственный бэкграунд любого вида для подходящего контейнера (напр. ConstraintLayout), зачем вам именно CardView нужно такой делать? - по сути она FrameLayout с фоном со скругленными углами

Comment: @pavlofff окей как сделатоь это через xml?

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете попробовать установить `background` для `CardView` и потом в коде вызвать у `CardView` метод `clipToOutline = true`